# Comparing User Input with String?

Tags: java

I am trying to create an ATM system with Java. This generates a code with Math.random and a pincode has to be entered by the user on registration. I am on the login section, and I am stuck with a problem of doing an if statement and not working but when I print them, they are the same (the user input and the variable which has to be compared with.)

I need help please.

```
JButton confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm");
       confirmButton.setBounds(185,200,268,25);
       confirmButton.setFont(title);
       loginPanel.add(confirmButton);
       confirmButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
               if(pinFieldobj.getText().equals(pincodes) && cardField.getText().equals(cardnoInt)){
                   transactionPanel();
               }
               else{
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect input");
                   System.out.println(cardField.getText());
                   System.out.println(cardnoInt);
                   System.out.println(pinFieldobj.getText());
                   System.out.println(pincodes);
                   login();
               }
           }
       });
```

[This](https://shrib.com/#YuU-qaJ4n1_K1DEQ0OI2) is the source code for those who need to see the full perspective of it.

Comment: Few remarks. First: you really need to learn how to use layout managers, and how to use buttons. The swing tutorial covers that. Second: cardnoInt is, I presume (because you haven't posted the code in the question), of type `int`. `cardField.getText()`, on the other hand, is presumably a String. A String will never, ever be equal to an int. You need to transform the int to a String or vice-versa, and then compare comparable things.

Comment: Thanks for helping @JBNizet I will try my best to improve on my buttons and layout managers. I managed to get it to work by turning int to String.